# GMT output from Apscheduler methods

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, apscheduler

I've written a simple house heating schedule program using `Apschedule(3.0.5)` on a `Raspberrypi(Jessie)`. I'm using the `next_run_time` method as a way to make a custom printable out akin to `print_jobs` method. However, the output is in `GMT` which is rather confusing as the computer is in central Europe and uses/outputs `CET` for all other purpose (locale is set for hungary, CET). Is there a way to return `CET` times and why is it doing it?

**Here is the problem part of the code:**

```
everything ={}
for thing in house.scheduler.get_jobs():
    everything[thing.id] = thing.next_run_time
#example output
"16.0_2": "Tue, 15 Dec 2015 15:00:00 GMT",
```

Answer (score 0):

This field is used internally to determine when the job should run next. If you want to display it in another timezone, you can use the [astimezone()](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) method of the datetime class, giving it your scheduler's timezone as the argument.

As an aside:

```
everything = {thing.id: thing.next_run_time for thing in house.scheduler.get_jobs()}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply - Out of interest, what advantages are there of using your construct for the generation of the dictionary?

Comment: This solution unfortunately doesn't work as thing.next_run_time.tzinfo states it is in 'Europe/Budapest'

Comment: A dictionary comprehension is 1 line of code compared to your 3 lines.